# How to compare the format of text between Excel and Access (like color, bold etc)

Tags: ms-access, excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, vba

In fact, what I am doing now is to realize the synchronization of Excel and Sharepoint, which means that Excel can update with the updating of Sharepoint, and the same for the inverse case.

As known, MS 2003 has no problem with this, but MS 2010 can just realize the fonction from Sharepoint -> Excel, but not the inverse way.

So I am thinking to add Access because there exists Access <-> Sharepoint, and so if I can realize la fonction Excel -> Access, that will solve my problem.

I have finished some parts of macros for this, and now I have realized the fundamental fonction of synchronization. However, there are some difficulties in dealing with the format of text. In Sharepoint and Access, to express the color is like this 
`<div><font color = "#ff0000">TEXT</font></div>,` however in excel I have no idea about the expression of the string.

So how to do it? All suggestions or answers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very broad question and covers alot of possibilities, and this isn't a complete answer, but for comparing HTML to VBA formatting, you would need to individually break down each formatting option and convert it from HTML to VBA and determine the properties applied to the text, just as you stated above. Then you would need individual VBA functions to specify what you want to compare from the text.

---

*That being said, this is just an example of how this can be achieved for font color comparison.*

Given:

```
'example html: <div><font color = "#ff0000">TEXT</font></div>
Dim HTML_text : HTML_text = "<div><font color = '#ff0000'>TEXT</font></div>"
Dim font_color : fontcolor = Mid(HTML_text, instr(HTML_text, "#"), 7)
```

Would return "#ff0000" as a variable `font_color` Then you would need the excel function to convert Hex(#FF0000) to RGB (taken from -> [Here](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=6324)):

```
Public Function HEXCOL2RGB(ByVal HexColor As String) As String
Dim Red As String
Dim Green As String
Dim Blue As String
Color = Replace(HexColor, "#", "") 
Red = Val("&H" & Mid(HexColor, 1, 2)) 
Green = Val("&H" & Mid(HexColor, 3, 2))
Blue = Val("&H" & Mid(HexColor, 5, 2))
HEXCOL2RGB = Red & "," & Green & "," & Blue
End Function
```

Then to extract the fonts RGB in Excel to the RGB you recieved from HTML you would need the  following function(taken from -> [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14281966/excel-formula-that-prints-cell-color-colorindex-or-rgb)):

```
Function FontColorRGB(Target As Range) As String
Dim N As Double
N = Target.Font.Color
FontColorRGB = Str(N Mod 256) & "," & Str(Int(N / 256) Mod 256) & "," & Str(Int(N / 256 / 256) Mod 256)
End Function
```

Then to finally pull it all together, you would utilize both functions:

```
Dim XLFontClr : XLFontClr = FontColorRGB("A1:A2")
Dim RGB_clr : RGB_clr = HEXCOL2RGB(font_color) 'Returns "Red,Green,Blue" in string form.

If XLFontClr = RGB_clr Then
     msgbox "web formatting and excel formatting compared successfully" 
End If
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Also, I wonder whether there exists a macro(add-in) which could connect one sharepoint fiche with many excel fiches, however each excel fiche could just modify some parts of the sharepoint fiche (maybe some colonnes)? That would save much time for me :D

Comment: I have found the method to synchronize Excel with Sharepoint. In fact there exist a patch which could help us to update a table(excel) with sharepoint. (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9345) However, we should creat a new zone in sharepoint, which means we should publish the table from excel to sharepoint and then we could update it to sharepoint.

Comment: So, to solve this problem, I have found an utile class: ListObject. (http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11426/update-list-from-excel-using-vba) There is a small exemple to help us to understand it. In fact by using the macro we could choose to upload a table  from sharepoint to excel and then keep the 2 in synchronization. PS: It seems that this function costs 69$ in some site.. So enjoy it! :D