# Get color code of the fill from a conditional formatting cell

Tags: html, excel, colors, fill, conditional-formatting

I want to color a world map with the colors I obtained in Excel trough conditional formatting. The process is automatic but I need the HTML code of the colors for each individual cell (there are 229 cells so manual solutions are off the tamble) of a range of cells that was colored trough a conditional formatting rule. Problem is **all solutions I found online so far only work for cells that are not "conditional formatted"** ie. their fill color was set manually.

The file I'm using to automatically color the map can be found here: https://app.box.com/s/yxur2ea2r7cswct80hdz

A solution like this that would work for conditionally formatted cells and return the result in HTML color code would be ideal: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14283150/4214058

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

Look at `cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color` (actually displayed) instead of `cell.Interior.Color` ('manually' set)

Comment: I tried to use it in this function:
Function FillColor(Target As Range) As Variant
    FillColor = Target.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
End Function

Returns an "VALUE!" error. I don't know what I've done wrong.

Comment: Found the issue: "DisplayFormat property does not work in user defined functions" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838814%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: Sorry, didn't know that. And didn't know that you want to call it from a user defined function. Thought you want to call a macro. Maybe you should redirect your formulas used to for the conditional formatting to 'helper cells' and refer to these cells from map and cells which need formatting.